# Any work around to show TextArea under bigobject

Tags: big-object

I am able to create and hold records in big object. Here's my issue with bigobject fields, I am able to insert the data with LongTextArea/TextArea fields, but I am unable to query the field. And even Salesforce is not showing up LongTextArea field while querying from workbench as Salesforce is not supporting LongTextArea. Is there any workaround to store and get the field info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am able to figure it out, everything is in permission set file. Adding LongTextArea field to the permission set file is mandatory to get/query the field.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to query the data (by query I hope you mean include that field in the select clause) including longtextarea fields. However you cannot use those fields to filter records or including in group by, or sort them.

The reason why that field is not showing up in Workbench or Salesforce may be the user you used doesn't have access to that field. Check field security.

Comment: Thank you for reminding field security, I am not sure that might be the cause but will try in that way.